# Twitter bootstrap v3+ dropdown : which element class do I need to listen to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

my question is simple but documentation or google is sparse about that...

I have a notification dropdown that I want to reload by ajax each time that exact dropdown is closed.

I just need to know which element do I need to listen to : the `.dropdown` ? `.dropdown-toggle` ? Or `.dropdown-menu` ?

Here is my code sample with IDs to be more specific :

```
<li class="dropdown" id='notif_drp'>
    <a id="notif_toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Open</a>
    <ul id='notif_ul' class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Notification 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind bootstrap's event, which is shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events).
There are 4 event you can use.

And I made an example. http://jsbin.com/gudevoxara/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 1):

From twitter bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events)

> All dropdown events are fired at the .dropdown-menu's parent element.

So for your example the `li` tag with class `dropdown` and id `notif_drp`
You can see it at [codepen](http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/bpPxOR?editors=1010)